# split("[^0-9a-zA-Z]+") shows empty strings in result

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to split text from file to words

```
split("[^0-9a-zA-Z]+")
```

but there are empty strings at result. How can i fix this problem?

length | number in array| word | count | %

```
2   [  1]  to       9   5.56 %
0   [  2]           6   3.70 %
5   [  3]  there        6   3.70 %
6   [  4]  result       3   1.85 %
4   [  5]  text         3   1.85 %
3   [  6]  but      3   1.85 %
```

output is:

```
I'm trying to split text from file to words

split("[^0-9a-zA-Z]+") 
but there are result empty strings too. Is there any solutions to solve this problem?
```

3 times pasted

Comment: Can you give an example of the problem you are having?

Comment: Please provide the input, what you get and what you expect to get.

Comment: I am not even sure how to parse your last comment...

Comment: Ok, it looks like we have input... can you show us an example of your expected output? I'm finding it difficult to understand your broken english, no offence.

Answer (score 2):

For `String.split`, the parameter you pass is a regex matching the *separator* of the terms.  The separator itself is removed.

Since your regex is matching words, you're actually removing the words and leaving the whitespace as terms.

E.g.:

The quick brown fox

will be splitted as follows

```
[The][ ][quick][ ][brown][ ][fox]
 Sep  0   Sep   1   Sep   2  Sep
```

resulting in an array of three single-space strings.

I'm guessing some of your words are not fully matching the regex, which is why you also get some of them in your result.

Solution: either do it the other way around (`myString.split('\\s')` seems like a good start), or use a matcher and iterate until it doesn't find anything.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29